# Filter two columns based on if they are within 100m2 of each other

Tags: qgis, filtering

[image]

I need to filter these two columns based on if they are within 100m2 of each other. I'm not familiar with query builder, so I tried some stuff but most didn't work. I would assume that the solution is somewhere in the query builder. As you can see, some rows almost have the same circumference. Those are the ones I need to select/filter. The other ones are not relevant.

Edit: So after I tried some stuff I found the following filter-expression:

```
"Area_m2" < "Area_m2_2"+100  AND  "Area_m2_2" < "Area_m2"+100
```

I think its correct and it does filter based on if the values are within a 100 of each other, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: a better query would be to abs(area_1 - area2) < 100